# How to change capitalization of GitHub repo?

Tags: github

Is is possible to rename:

https://github.com/feklee/multitrans

to:

https://github.com/feklee/MultiTrans

?

*If so, how?*

Comment: You might make a new repo and `git push`  the old one into it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I tried renaming it via GitHub settings, but then got a message that the repo already exists: GitHub repo names are not case sensitive. Anyhow, I now deleted the repo and am in the process of recreating it. Asides from changing capitalization, this allows me to remove two multi MB video files (for documentation) which made the repo unnecessarily heavy. All that is not so much fun when on a train, going through lots of tunnels, having a flaky connection…

Comment: In unix, unless made to otherwise, there is no different between the repo names. Maybe github is case insensitive?

Comment: @phd Thanks! The answers of that duplicate suggest renaming to sth. completely different, then back. That's fine. I thought about that too, but didn't try it, worrying about undesired consequences and not being sure if it works.

Comment: but lowercase is so much better ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg Indeed! In this case it's an Arduino library, however, and camel case is standard.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your project, you can change the name. It is the very first field at https://github.com/feklee/multitrans/settings. If you edit that field, the rename button will become available.

Comment: Before posting the question, I tried renaming via GitHub settings, then got a message that the repo already exists: GitHub repo names are not case sensitive.